# Convert from jxl excel parser to Apache Poi?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have to convert from logic from `jxl` parser to Apache `poi`.

I want fo safe existing logic.

Here is snippet with `jxl`:

```
public class Ancillaries {

    private Workbook workbook;
    private EntryParser shortParser;
    private EntryParser longParser;
    private Sheet sheet;

    private Cell lowShortStart;
    private Cell lowShortEnd;
    private Cell highShortStart;
    private Cell highShortEnd;
    private Cell lowLongStart;
    private Cell lowLongEnd;
    private Cell highLongStart;
    private Cell highLongEnd;

    public Ancillaries(File xls, String sheetName) {
        try {
            workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(xls);
            sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);
            shortParser = new EntryParser();
            longParser = new EntryParser();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("can not find xls file", e);
        }
    }

    public Ancillaries(String xls, String sheetName) {
        this(new File(xls), sheetName);
    }

    public List<BagPricing> parse() {
        List<BagPricing> bags = new ArrayList<BagPricing>();

        List<BagPricing> lowSeasonBagsS = shortParser.getTable(lowShortStart, lowShortEnd, Haul.SHORT_HAUL, Season.LOW);
        List<BagPricing> highSeasonBagsS = shortParser.getTable(highShortStart, highShortEnd, Haul.SHORT_HAUL, Season.HIGH);

        List<BagPricing> lowSeasonBagsL = longParser.getTable(lowLongStart, lowLongEnd, Haul.LONG_HAUL, Season.LOW);
        List<BagPricing> highSeasonBagsL = longParser.getTable(highLongStart, highLongEnd, Haul.LONG_HAUL, Season.HIGH);

        bags.addAll(lowSeasonBagsS);
        bags.addAll(highSeasonBagsS);
        bags.addAll(lowSeasonBagsL);
        bags.addAll(highSeasonBagsL);
        return bags;
    }

    public void setDefault() {
        setRowKey("C30", "AR30");
        setLowSeasonShort("D30", "U40");
        setHighSeasonShort("W30", "AN40");
        setLowSeasonLong("AR30", "BI42");
        setHighSeasonLong("BK30", "CC42");
    }

    public void setRowKey(String shortCell, String longSell) {
        shortParser.rowKey = sheet.getCell(shortCell).getColumn();
        longParser.rowKey = sheet.getCell(longSell).getColumn();
    }

    public void setLowSeasonShort(String startCell, String endCell) {
        this.lowShortStart = sheet.getCell(startCell);
        this.lowShortEnd = sheet.getCell(endCell);
    }

    public void setHighSeasonShort(String startCell, String endCell) {
        this.highShortStart = sheet.getCell(startCell);
        this.highShortEnd = sheet.getCell(endCell);
    }

    public void setLowSeasonLong(String startCell, String endCell) {
        this.lowLongStart = sheet.getCell(startCell);
        this.lowLongEnd = sheet.getCell(endCell);
    }

    public void setHighSeasonLong(String startCell, String endCell) {
        this.highLongStart = sheet.getCell(startCell);
        this.highLongEnd = sheet.getCell(endCell);
    }
```

I want to know how to rechange logic from `setDefault()` to using [Apache Poi](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html). I tried to find somethig similar at poi API. But withot suceess.

***Any suggestions?***